# jQuery.slideDown + jQuery.focus() getting called twice and not working?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a weird problem.

I am trying to, when a checkbox is clicked, have a text box `slideDown()` then call the `.focus()` on the `textarea` but....

1. It doesn't focus - i.e. it doesn't put the cursor there.
2. It calls the `.focus()` function twice? (as seen by the `console.log()`)

Any help would be appreciated!

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7nSXu/1/) - http://jsfiddle.net/7nSXu/1/

Starting:
[image]

After Click:

[image]

---

### HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span3">
        <p>
            <input type="checkbox" name="items[46][46]" value="46" style="margin-bottom: 6px;" class="reveal_below" data-item-id="46">                                <strong>Product</strong>
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class=" span4 hidden_below hidden_below__46" style="display:none">
        <textarea style="width: 100%;height:6em;" placeholder="Return notes..." name="items[46][customer_item_return_notes]" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <hr style="display:none" class="hidden_below__46">
</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    $('.reveal_below').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var item_id = $(this).attr('data-item-id');
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('.hidden_below__' + item_id).slideDown(function() {
                console.log('CALLING FOCUS');
                $('.hidden_below__' + item_id).focus();
            })
        } else {
            $('.hidden_below__' + item_id).slideUp();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are sliding 2 elements so the callback is executed twice, you can use `.promise()` and `.done()` methods, also you should select the textarea and then call the `.focus()` function:

```
$(function() {
    $('.reveal_below').on('change', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var item_id = $(this).attr('data-item-id');
        if (this.checked) {
            $('.hidden_below__' + item_id)
                 .slideDown()
                 .promise()
                 .done(function() {
                    // console.log('CALLING FOCUS');
                    this.find('textarea').focus();
                 });
        } else {
            $('.hidden_below__' + item_id).slideUp();
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4xJde/3/

Comment: That is cool - I've never seen those two functions `.promise()` or `.done()` THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are setting focus on hr. You are doing too many unnecessary things here.

Try this **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/EquSUJO/2/edit)**:

```
$(function() {
$('.reveal_below').on('click', function(e) {
    var item_id = $(this).attr('data-item-id');
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('.hidden_below__' + item_id).slideDown().closest('div').find('textarea').focus();
        }else {
        $('.hidden_below__' + item_id).slideUp();
    }
 });
});
```